# Create temporary link for download

Tags: asp.net, file, download, hyperlink, html

I use ASP.NET
I need to give user temporary link for downloading file from server.
It should be a temporary link (page), which is available for a short time (12 hours for example). How can I generate this link (or temporary web page with link)?

Answer (score 11):

Here's a reasonably complete example.

First a function to create a short hex string using a secret salt plus an expiry time:

```
public static string MakeExpiryHash(DateTime expiry)
{
    const string salt = "some random bytes";
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(salt + expiry.ToString("s"));
    using (var sha = System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1.Create())
        return string.Concat(sha.ComputeHash(bytes).Select(b => b.ToString("x2"))).Substring(8);
}
```

Then a snippet that generates a link with a one week expiry:

```
DateTime expires = DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromDays(7);
string hash = MakeExpiryHash(expires);
string link = string.Format("http://myhost/Download?exp={0}&k={1}", expires.ToString("s"), hash);
```

Finally the download page for sending a file if a valid link was given:

```
DateTime expires = DateTime.Parse(Request.Params["exp"]);
string hash = MakeExpiryHash(expires);
if (Request.Params["k"] == hash)
{
    if (expires < DateTime.UtcNow)
    {
        // Link has expired
    }
    else
    {
        string filename = "<Path to file>";
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(Server.MapPath(filename));
        Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + filename);
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fi.Length.ToString());
        Response.WriteFile(fi.FullName);
        Response.Flush();
    }
}
else
{
    // Invalid link
}
```

Which you should certainly wrap in some exception handling to catch mangled requests.

Comment: just have in mind that sending a datetime value with seconds will result in a  potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:)

Comment: Response.WriteFile does a good way?i think it downloads file on server then downloads to users computer.(if my files be on other server)

Answer (score 9):

```
http://example.com/download/document.pdf?token=<token>
```

The `<token>` part is key here. If you don't want to involve a database, encrypt link creation time, convert it to URL-safe Base64 representation and give user that URL. When it's requested, decrypt `token` and compare date stored in there with current date and time.

Alternatively, you can have a separate `DownloadTokens` table wich will map said `token`s (which can be GUIDs) to expiration dates.

Comment: I like this idea a lot.  My suggestion to enhance it would be to use a handler and encrypt the document to be downloaded along with the time.  Else you'll have to use a httpmodule or something to prevent the user from just cutting the token off of the URL.

Comment: @Kevin Why encrypt the document? True, you'll need a separate `IHttpHandler` here, but that's no big deal really.

Comment: Actually, I meant to encrypt the name of the document.  You can use SSL if you want to encrypt the document itself.
The reason I suggest encrypting the name of the doc is because I work for a law firm and many docs are confidential and even the name is confidential. By encrypting the doc within the URL, you make it harder for someone to pull a doc they're not supposed to.

Answer (score 3):

Append a timestamp to the URL, in the querystring:

```
page.aspx?time=2011-06-22T22:12
```

Check the timestamp against the current time.

To avoid the user changing the timestamp by himself, also compute some secret hash over the timestamp, and also append that to the querystring:

```
page.aspx?time=2011-06-22T22:12&timehash=4503285032
```

As hash you can do something like the sum of all fields in the DateTime modulo some prime number, or the SHA1 sum of the string representation of the time. Now the user will not be able to change the timestamp without knowing the correct hash. In your page.aspx, you check the given hash against the hash of the timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

There's a million ways to do it.

The way I did once for a project was to generate a unique key and use a dynamic downloader script to stream the file. when the file request was made the key was generated and stored in db with a creation time and file requested. you build a link to the download script and passed in the key. from there it was easy enough to keep track of expiration.

Answer (score 1):

llya

I'll assume you're not requiring any authentication and security isn't an issue - that is if anyone gets the URL they will also beable to download the file.

Personally I'd create a HttpHandler and then create some unique string that you can append to the URL.

Then within the ProcessRequest void test the encoded param to see if it's still viable (with in your specified time-frame) if so use BinaryWrite to render the File or if not you can render some HTML using Response.Write("Expired")

Something like :

```cs
public class TimeHandler : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
{
    public void ProcessRequest ( HttpContext context )
    {
    
        if( this.my_check_has_expired( this.Context.Request.Params["my_token"] ) )
        {
            // Has Expired 

            context.Response.Write( "URL Has Expired" );
            return;
        }

        // Render the File
        Stream stream = new FileStream( File_Name , FileMode.Open );

        /* read the bytes from the file */
        byte[] aBytes = new byte[(int)oStream.Length];
        stream.Read( aBytes, 0, (int)oStream.Length );
        stream.Close( ); 

        // Set Headers
        context.Response.AddHeader( "Content-Length", aBytes.Length.ToString( ) );
        // ContentType needs to be set also you can force Save As if you require

        // Send the buffer
        context.Response.BinaryWrite( aBytes );                            

    }
}
```

You need to then setup the Handler in IIS, but that a bit different depending on the version you're using.

Comment: Strictally you don't need IRequireSession State depends if you are also doing some form of authentication or session tracking.