# Enterprise distribution of our app(ios app) through secure website

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipa

We are facing with a problem while enterprise distribution of our app through secure website. Website is windows authentication enabled and running on IIS 7.5, when user opens the list of applications page website requires domain username and password. After successful login, user press the download button and start the itms-services manifest download action website again prompts username-password dialog box. After entering the credentials 3 or 4 times ipa can be downloaded. Do you have any resolution for asking the credentials once in a session?

Comment: This web site is working smootly on the Android Phone. So, do you have any opinion? @Krunal

Comment: i can not share due to bank policy. But you can ask me, what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue in our project by creating single use URLs for both the manifest and IPA files.

An explanation for ASP.NET may be found in the SO answer for [Create temporary link for download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703201/create-temporary-link-for-download).

We implemented this in 2013 and, given the small niche, it's not surprising that direct app install hasn't been improved upon.

Another solution (given the enterprise context) might be using an [Mobile Device Management](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/MobileDeviceManagementProtocolRef/1-Introduction/Introduction.html) but that would be a significant increase in complexity.