# Best method(s) to hide image and video browser links and prevent downloading?

Tags: image, security, video, browser, blob

Acknowledging that there's no way to 100% prevent video/image piracy on a website, there are four good tools to try and prevent it (see following list).  Which one, or combination, works best?  And why?

(1) disable context menu - user can still "View Source"

(2) use server URL rewrite - masks the true folder, but the user can just use the mask directly to download

(3) use createObjectURL blob and revokeObjectURL - the user can search the javascript and find the original filename/directory which got blobbed, no?

(4) use one-time temporary resource URL - seems like the best solution to me...thoughts?

Which one, or combination, works best?  And why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, One-time temporary resource URL is preferable. Temporary URL should be expired after one-time usage and there should be sufficient expiry time, i.e. expire after 1 minute to 1 hour time depends on contents. If streaming is not required, you can manage resources to download directly.

Comment: I was thinking along the same lines and have created something like this in ASP but I've over-complicated it.  I saw this example, too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703201/create-temporary-link-for-download .  But, what I really want, is to craft a one-time usage URL which doesn't depend on time, just the one-time usage - I can store the key in a Session variable and remove it after the one usage.  (hopefully in VB, but I can read C#, too)

Comment: Hmm right, atleast you can implement one-time key and remove it after one usage. Additionally, if you store it as a session variable, it will long till the session is active. So, once the session is expired, it will be expired. Later, you can implement timeout whenever necessary as per application's context.