# how to create expire token firebase cloud function?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, token, firebase-dynamic-links

I want to create and send Link "firebase dynamic link" with expire token with firebase cloud function that :

- only the user who received the mail can use it.
- Token will be expire after 24 hour.

```
exports.orderDynamicLink = functions.database
  .ref("order/{orderId}")
  .onWrite((event) => {
    const options = {
      method: "POST",
      uri: `https://firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com/v1/shortLinks?key=${
        functions.config().applinks.key
      }`,
```

// I want to generate and add here the expire token

```
      body: {
        dynamicLinkInfo: {
          domainUriPrefix: "https://example.page.link",
          link: "https://www.example.com/",
          androidInfo: {
            androidPackageName: "com.example.android",
          },
          iosInfo: {
            iosBundleId: "com.example.ios",
          },
        },
      },
      json: true,
    };

    request(options).then(function (parsedBody) {
      console.log(parsedBody);
      sendEmailLink(parsedBody.shortLink);
      return parsedBody.shortLink;
    });
  });

function sendEmailLink(link) {
  //google account credentials used to send email
  var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
      user: "***********@gmail.com",
      pass: "yourpassword",
    },
  });

  const mailOptions = {
    from: `***********`,
    to: snap.data().email,
    subject: "contact form message",
    html: `<h1> tou can make a Order using this link</h1>
                                <p>
                                   <b>link: </b>${link}<br>
                                </p>`,
  };

  return transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, data) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
      return;
    }
    console.log("Sent!");
  });
}
```

I want to know how to achieve that : how can I create the token, how to make it expire ? how to store it ? and how to verify it when the user use the link if it valid or not ? with firebase cloud function .

Sorry for my bad English .

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use [Manage Session Cookies](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies), which is stored at server side and you can set custom expiration times from 5 minutes to 2 weeks.

Or you could also set up custom expiry logic, pass timestamp and other params to the link URL, and then add time checking logic at server side to validate. The [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703201/create-temporary-link-for-download/16987555) provides more information on how to do it.